# Printable Page with all Posts from Tag

Tags: posts, filters, jquery

We are transitioning our company newsletter to Wordpress. Our old site is basic HTML/CSS/JS. On that site, we had a "Print All Stories" button that would pull every article from that issue in a printable format. Is there a way to accomplish in WP by filtering posts by either category or tag onto a printable page like the one below?

(See http://ddmonews.com/insightfulsmiles/octnov2016/print-all-stories.html)

It used the following JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="common/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var stories = ['story1.php', 'story2.php', 'story3.php', 'efn_adv.php', 'efn_ddmo.php', 'efn_ddsc.php', 'ghsh1.php', 'ghsh2.php', 'ghsh3.php', 'ghsh4.php', 'ghsh5.php', 'npnf_ddmo.php', 'npnf_deniserv.php', 'atwc_adv.php', 'atwc_ddmo.php', 'familyphotos1.php', 'familyphotos2.php', 'familyphotos3.php', ];

    function nextLoad(i) {
        if(i < stories.length) {
            loadContent(stories[i]+' div.content', i);
        }
    }
    function loadContent(toLoad, i) {  
        $('#temp').load(toLoad,'',function(){appendContent(i);});
    }
    function appendContent(i) {
        $('#content').append($('#temp').html());
        i++;
        nextLoad(i);
    }
    nextLoad(0);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking for a solution that would 'print' the relevant articles to a pdf format, which could then be printed.  Search the plugins directory for terms such as 'posts to pdf' to find one that would allow you to print all posts in a certain category or with a certain tag.